# When updating a row in a gridview catch constraint unique value error in a label

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview and sqldatasource to bind data from datatable to the gridview .

When I'm updating a value from a cell with a new one , and the value already exists in other cell of the gridview , I will get contraint error for unique value.

How can I catch that error and display in a label a text to warn the user the value already exists?
So , I'm not adding something to gridview from an event and there's nothing I can catch. I'm just editing the gridview.

Thanks

Comment: you can do that easily if you define GridView RowUpdating event

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to define your inserting/inserted handler and the arguments to those handlers contain any exception thrown from the database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.inserted.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasourcestatuseventargs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Add a handler for `OnRowUpdated` and handle the error there:

Example:

```
OnRowUpdated="GridViewUpdateEventHandler"


protected void GridViewUpdateEventHandler(Object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Exception!=null)
    {
       lblForError.Text="Unable to update"; //etc
    }
}
```

Others suggest that you do it on `OnRowUpdating` but this is if you want to validate **before** actually allowing the update to proceed. If you decide that you want to go this route, all you need to do is set `e.Cancel` to True on the `GridViewUpdateEventArgs` parameter as so:

```
e.Cancel=true;
```

Comment: Okay I will test it when I'm back home . thanks for your help